# Combine incremental sequence with a fixed columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
data.frame(x=c(1,2,3), y=c(4,5,6))

  x y
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

For each row, I want to repeat x and y for each element within a given sequence, where the sequence is:

```
E=seq(0,0.2,by=0.1)
```

So when combined this would give:

```
  x y E
1 1 4 0
2 1 4 0.1
3 1 4 0.2
4 2 5 0
5 2 5 0.1
6 2 5 0.2
7 3 6 0
8 3 6 0.1
9 3 6 0.2
```

I can not seem to achieve this with `expand.grid` - seems to give me all possible combinations. Am I after a cartesian product?

Comment: I was asking specifically if this was a cartesian product. I dont see this mentioned in the suggested answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are looking for cartesian product but base `expand.grid` cannot handle dataframes.

You can use `tidyr` functions here :

```
tidyr::expand_grid(df, E)

# A tibble: 9 x 3
#      x     y     E
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     4   0  
#2     1     4   0.1
#3     1     4   0.2
#4     2     5   0  
#5     2     5   0.1
#6     2     5   0.2
#7     3     6   0  
#8     3     6   0.1
#9     3     6   0.2
```

Or with `crossing`

```
tidyr::crossing(df, E)
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x=c(1,2,3), y=c(4,5,6))

dt[,.(E=seq(0,0.2,by=0.1)),by=.(x,y)]
#>    x y   E
#> 1: 1 4 0.0
#> 2: 1 4 0.1
#> 3: 1 4 0.2
#> 4: 2 5 0.0
#> 5: 2 5 0.1
#> 6: 2 5 0.2
#> 7: 3 6 0.0
#> 8: 3 6 0.1
#> 9: 3 6 0.2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>